# Encountering error while using ChangeNotifierProvider.value in Gridview.builder

Tags: flutter, hybrid-mobile-app, flutter-dependencies, flutter-change-notifier

> This is likely a mistake and is unsupported.
>   If you're in this situation, consider passing a `key` unique to each individual constructor.

Above is the error which reflects on Running the code with a flutter widget as a child:-

```
    GridView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      itemCount: products.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: products[i],
        child: ProductItem(
            ),
      ),
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This situation can be tackled by using keys as specified:-

```
    GridView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      itemCount: products.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        key: Key("item$i"),
        value: products[i],
        child: ProductItem(
            ),
      ),
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
      ),
    )
```